# How to post image binary to flask rest in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

### Context

I created a python flask restful service to interact with my MySQL database. I just added a new path to get images and to save it. It works when I tested it with python requests library but I have no idea how to implement this into html and AJAX javascript.

### What I Tried

- I tried to simply google my question in different ways of phrasing it and whatnot but I couldn't find anything useful

---

### What i'm expecting at the end

I simply want to be able to send an image from html webpage to my flask server and have It save the file.

---

## Code

### Python code

```
class process_image(Resource):
    def post(self):
        file = request.files['image']

        file.save('thephotisdfhghdfghfgh.jpg')

        return(200)
api.add_resource(process_image, '/image')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Request command

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/image'
my_img = {'image': open('test.jpg', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=my_img)
```

Comment: So you want to be able to upload a file to a Flask app from JavaScript?

Comment: @ajskateboarder pretty much yeah